# Morocco Post Code Shapefiles

Tags: data-request, geocoding, postal-code, geospatial

I'm searching for the post codes shapefiles of Morocco, anyone have an ideas where I can find those.. ?? I searched on google but I didn't find what I was looking for..

Can be open source.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at OpenStreetMap (OSM).

Municipalities in Morocco are represented using the OSM tag `admin_level=8`, according to this [page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative).

You can query the OSM data using the overpass turbo website: use the wizard and type `boundary=* and admin_level=8 in Morocco`. This results in this query: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/pJr. According to OSM, there are 1497 objects (pois). I don't know if the data is complete. When zooming on the map, some of the polygons have a strange shape (overlapping polygons).